# Retrieivng mysql data using PERL and jquery-ajax

Tags: mysql, perl, html, jquery

I am creating a web page that has 3 basic elements, select box, button, & table.  From a high level, the user selects an element, and clicks the button.  When the button is clicked, a PERL script is executed that puts data in a table in a mySQL db. All those things work successfully.

Now, I am trying to return the DB table values to my HTML file with a dynamic table.  But every source I find has my CGI file writing html tags.  I don't feel this is right, because I don't understand home my CGI knows the table ID, even though I am passing the value.  Also, I know my js file is incorrect, having two separate AJAX calls, but that is home I am logically processing in my head.

I am not sure what comes first, fixing the CGI or JS file.

HTML Code (index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" class="jsbin" src="C:/xampp/DataTables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/RunPerlScript.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/table.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1></h1>
        </header>
        <form name="myForm" method="GET" action="">
            <select id="cdLDAP" >
                <option/>
            </select>
            <input type="button"  id="btn_run" name="btn_run" value="Run"></input>
        </form>
        <table id="results_table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Perl (CGI):

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl -T
    use CGI;
    use DBI;
    use strict;
    use warnings;

    # read the CGI params
    my $cgi = CGI->new;
    my $inputselection = $cgi->param("cdLDAP");
    my $html_table = $cgi->param("html_table_results");
    my ($base_dn, $tblname);
    #my $password = $cgi->param("password");

    #my $inputselection = "Disabled Users";
    #LDAP Connection parameters
    if ($inputselection eq "Disabled Users") {
        $base_dn = "";
        $tblname = "disabled_user";
    } elsif ($inputselection eq "") {
        $base_dn = "";
        $tblname = "service_account";
    } elsif ($inputselection eq "") {
        $base_dn = "";
        $tblname = "";
    } else {
        die;
    }

    # connect to the database
    my ($platform,$database,$host,$port,$db_user,$pw) = ("mysql","results","localhost","3306","resultsuser","mysql123");
    my $dsn = "DBI:$platform:database=$database,host=$host,port=$port";
    my $connect = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=$database;host=$host",$db_user,$pw,{RaiseError => 1});

    #query db to get results set for table output
    my $query_results = "SELECT * FROM " . $tblname;
    my $query_handle = "";
    $query_handle = $connect->prepare($query_results) or die $connect->errstr;
    $query_handle->execute() or die $query_handle->errstr;

    print header;
    # HTML for the beginning of the table
    # we are putting a border around the table for effect
    print "<table border=\"1\" width=\"800\"> \n";

    # print your table column headers
    print "<tr><td>User ID</td><td>Status</td><td>Last Password Reset</td><td>Reset Needed?</td></tr>\n";

    my (@data,$uid,$status,$pwlstset,$resetmsg);

    # retrieve the values returned from executing your SQL statement
    foreach (@data = $query_handle->fetchrow_array()) {
    $uid = $data[0];
    $status = $data[1];
    $pwlstset = $data[2];
    $resetmsg = $data[3];

    # print your table rows
    print "<tr><td>$uid</td><td>$status</td><td>$pwlstset</td><td>$resetmsg</td></tr>\n";

    }

    # close your table
    print "</table>\n";

    # exit the script
    exit;
```

JS/JQuery/AJAX:

```
$(function() {
    $('#btn_run').click(function() {
        var tblname = $('#cdLDAP').val();
        var html_table = $('#results_table').attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/perl/cgitest.pl", // URL of the Perl script that queries LDPA and inputs to mySQL
            data: "cdLDAP=" +tblname,
            // script call was *not* successful
            error: function() { 
                alert("ERROR!");
            }, // error 
            // script call was successful 
            // data contains the JSON values returned by the Perl script 
            success: function(data){
                alert("success!");
            } // success
        }); // ajax
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/perl/cgitest2.pl", // URL of the Perl script that retirves data from mySQL
            data: "cdLDAP=" +tblname +",html_table_results=" +html_table,
            // script call was *not* successful
            error: function() { 
                alert("ERROR!");
            }, // error 
            // script call was successful 
            // data contains the JSON values returned by the Perl script 
            success: function(data){
                alert("success!");
            } // success
        }); // ajax
    });
});
```

So here is what I need some help with:
1) Should my PERL script be writing the html tags?  If yes, how do I write to `index.html` and not a new html file?
2) If the table structure is created by the jquery file, a good teaching source would eb appreciated, because I am trying to be taught how to fish, and not given a fish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should my PERL script be writing the html tags?

There is [no such thing as PERL](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq1.html#What%27s-the-difference-between-%22perl%22-and-%22Perl%22%3f).

If you want to use Ajax to dynamically update a page (note that you should be using [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)) then there are two basic approaches you can take:

1. Server returns data in a clean data structure (possibly JSON)
2. Server returns a fragment of HTML

I'm generally in favour of the former approach (in which case you would construct an array of hashrefs in your Perl, run it through [a JSON module](https://metacpan.org/module/JSON) and then output it with an `application/json` Content-Type HTTP header.

Given that some versions of Internet Explorer have problems with trying to edit the `innerHTML` of a table element, this makes the first option better.

> If yes, how do I write to index.html and not a new html file?

You don't write to a file at all. You return the data via STDOUT and the webserver passes it back to the client.

> If the table structure is created by the jquery file, a good teaching source would eb appreciated

http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/

Comment: I am not familar with json but will this work or do I still need to encode it? `my %json_hash = ();
foreach (@data = $query_handle->fetchrow_array()) 
 {
 %json_hash = (
    "key" => "User ID",
    "val" => $data[0],
    "key" => "Status",
    "val" => $data[1],
    "key" => "Last Password Reset",
    "val" => $data[2],
    "key" => "Reset Needed",
    "val" => $data[3]
    )
 }`
Does this create an entire hash or just one for a given entry and keeps getting wiped out?  Also, from the `encode` documentation, by creating this as a hash, I won't have to use `encode` correct assumption?

Comment: Leaving the JSON aside for the moment, that won't work as a Perl data structure. I don't understand why you are using "key" and "val" as key names. You certainly can't use the same key multiple times in a single hash. You are also going to overwrite `%json_hash` each time you go over the loop as you do nothing with it (e.g. append a reference to it to an array). When it comes to the JSON, you will need to convert your Perl data structure into JSON (or another string based serialisation) before you send it over the wire.

Comment: https://github.com/dorward/simple-ajax-demo/blob/master/webroot/demo.pl might be useful.

Comment: Ok, so forgetting the JSON for now, bc I get that I will have to `encode.` I think I fix my hash, but can I append it like I have: `foreach (@data = $query_handle->fetchrow_array()) 
 {
 %json_hash = (
    %json_hash,
    "User ID" => $data[0],
    "Status" => $data[1],
    "Last Password Reset" => $data[2],
    "Reset Needed" => $data[3]
    )}`

TY Quentin

Comment: Now you are overwriting the hash with a copy of whatever it holds plus some duplicate keys. You can't have duplicate keys. You need to store a reference to the hash in an array.

Comment: I am selecting from a DB table that has a PK of User ID, so that will never be duplicated.  How will I have duplicate keys, if each row of the DB table is unique? But this is what I have coded:
`my %json_hash = ();
my @temp_array =[];
my $hash_ref;
my $counter = 0;
foreach (@data = $query_handle->fetchrow_array()) 
 {
 %json_hash = (
    "User ID" => $data[0],
    "Status" => $data[1],
    "Last Password Reset" => $data[2],
    "Reset Needed" => $data[3]
    )
 $hash_ref = \%json_hash;
 @temp_array[$counter] = $hash_ref;
 $counter++;
}`
TY

Comment: I am still struggling after 2+ days.  My code is still failing with this code:
`my %json_hash = ();
my $json_text;
my $json;
my @temp_array =[];
my $temp_array;
my $hash_ref;
my $counter = 0;
foreach (@data = $query_handle->fetchrow_array()) 
 {
 %json_hash = (
    "User ID" => $data[0],
    "Status" => $data[1],
    "Last Password Reset" => $data[2],
    "Reset Needed" => $data[3]
    );
 $hash_ref = \%json_hash;
 $temp_array[$counter] = $hash_ref;
 $counter++;
 }
my $c2=0;
while ($c2 < $counter)
 {
  print $json_text = $json->encode($temp_array[$c2]) . "\n";
  $c2++;
 }`
TY for hlp

Comment: It might help if you didn't assign an array reference to `@temp_array`. Why do you have `@temp_array` and `$temp_array`? Why do you have a counter instead of just using `push()`? Why are you declaring `%json_hash` and `$hash_ref` outside the scope of the `foreach` loop? Are you using strict and warnings? How is the code "failing"? What errors are you getting? Why are you calling `$json->encode` on the array members in a loop instead of calling it on the array itself?

Comment: In reference to the `@temp_array` v `$temp_array`, I tried the array first, and I never deleted it.  I guess if I used `push()`, then I would go back to `$temp_array`  I declare those variables outside the loop because I am bad at variable scope, and I tend to shy away from "in loop" scoping.  I am calling `$json->encode` on each member because I was testing the function out in a loop to make sure each element was correct. It is a "test" setup until I get it to work. Also, I kept getting a warning on using `@temp_array` so that is why I did it that way too.

Comment: I am no longer receiving a specific error.  My firebug and my error:function() in jquery are saying I get an error, but my script is not throwing the error, but it may still have to do with my error.

Comment: My `$json_text` returns `[]`. But I have tested this lop thoroughly to make sure, via `cmd` that I get the results I want in the array. 
`while (@data = $query_handle->fetchrow_array()) 
 {
 print $temp_array = @data;
 my %json_hash = ();
 my $hash_ref;
 %json_hash = (
    "User ID" => $data[0],
    "Status" => $data[1],
    "Last Password Reset" => $data[2],
    "Reset Needed" => $data[3]
    );
 $hash_ref = \%json_hash;
 push (@temp_array, $hash_ref);
 } 
print $json_text = $json->encode(@temp_array) . "\n";